# Grails 1.3 criteria join or subquery on unassociated table

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have a simple domain object

```
def MyDomain{
  String id
  String userId
  String blah

}
```

and a user Id domain object

```
def User{
  String id //maps to user_id column, ommitted from example
  String firstName
  String lastName
}
```

Within grails 1.3.7, is there a way to join the tables together using criteria?  We have many (80+) domain objects that use dynamically built criteria to do row lookups.  We recently have needed to add a User Name to each of these row lookups but would like to avoid going through and modifying that many domain objects if possible, especially since the data is small.

I have looked at DetachedCriteria, but this is only applicable for grails 2.0+ and upgrading is not an option just for this.  Other options I have seen involve putting User as a field in the MyDomain definition.  Is there a better way of doing this without all that overhead?  The corresponding query would be similar to:

```
select md.id, md.userId from myDomain md , user u where md.user_id = u.user_id order by     u.last_name, pu.first_name;
```

Comment: What overhead are you talking about? Why would adding a field of type User have more overhead than adding a field of type String?

Comment: The actual coding overhead of adding a field to over 80 domain objects, not overhead in regards to performance

Comment: Another option which I don't think will work (I would try, but away from my work computer now) is adding SQL to the end of the criteria.  As I understand it though, SQLRestriction is for adding a 'restriction' to the end of the query, rather than simply adding a subquery

Comment: For now we are adding the domain reference to User into the domains.  However, I'd still be interested in seeing if there is a solution to this.